# Unit of work pattern and entity framework: IObjectContextStorage?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Does anyone know in which namespace IObjectContextStorage could be found? or should I implement this interface in my application? I'm reading this article: http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such interface exist in .NET framework. It is interface defined in [source code](http://code.google.com/p/ef4prs/source/browse/trunk/Infrastructure.Data.EntityFramework/IObjectContextStorage.cs?spec=svn23&r=23) for that article.